# What is the possibility of getting a head or tail if the observer lies 1% of time?

Tags: probability

Supposing your friend flips a coin, but $1\%$ of time he will lie about the result. When that happens, if it's head he will report tail, and if it's tail he will report head. What is the probability of getting a head?

At first I thought it's $ 50\% × 99\% $, but then isn't that it should still be $50\%$? Because if it's the former case, then $ 50\% × 99\% + 50\% × 99\% = 0.99 < 1$

This problem is taken from this paper: [Understanding the Basics of NGS: From Mechanism to Variant Calling](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4633438/)

Comment: It's still 50 percent. It may be easier to imagine that first the friend flips a coin to decide to lie. After the lying coin is flipped, your friend flips the fair coin. In both the 'will lie' and 'will not lie' worlds, the probability of the outcome of the fair coin being reported heads is 50 percent. So, even though you do not know which world we are in because your friends lie-coin is hidden, you will see a 'heads' being reported half the time. (This is assuming that your friends decision to lie is independent of the coin flip.)

Comment: What does the question mean?  How is the probability of getting heads affected by his lying or not?

Comment: Are you asking for the probability that the coin lands on heads, or the probability that the friend says heads? Or the probability that the coin landed on heads given that the friend said heads?

Comment: I think you have oversimplified the example in the paper, which may be closer to: your friend chooses a fair coin or a double-tailed coin (with the fair coin being twice as likely as the double tailed coin).  They flip it, say, $8$ times and say it was heads once.  What is the probability they originally chose the fair coin, given that they lie about the result of a flip $1\%$ of the time?

Comment: @Henry yes. I'm building necessary knowledge to find the formula for the problem in the paper. My knowledge is rusty. Anyway, if you have read the paper, do you know how to construct the solution? I suppose it would use the binomial distribution, but beyond that I'm stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case $1$: $H$, friend doesnt lie

$$0.99\cdot 0.5$$

Case $2$: $T$, friend lies

$$0.01 \cdot 0.5$$

Summing up both cases,
$$(0.99+0.01)\cdot 0.5=0.5$$

Alternative:
It can be deduced immediately that $P(H)=0.5$. Why? A coin flip can either by Heads or Tails, Can you see why the probabilities are equal?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability). In this case, the calculation goes as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}
P[\text{coin} & =\text{head}]=P[\text{coin}=\text{head}\mid\text{friend}=\text{truth}]+P[\text{coin}=\text{tail}\mid\text{friend}=\text{lie}]\\
&=P[\text{coin}=\text{head}]P[\text{friend}=\text{truth}]+P[\text{coin}=\text{tail}]P[\text{friend}=\text{lie}]\\
&=0.5\cdot0.99+0.5\cdot0.01\\
&=0.5
\end{aligned}$$